# How to escape Javascript in HTML string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am populating html tag inside jquery looping. It means my html code is located inside string. Everything is okay but I can't figure out how to retrieve javascript parameter inside my html code.

I have tried using \ (backslash) or ` (backtick) to escape but still fails.

```
read_html += "https://example.org" + val.poster_path;
read_html += "<img src='https://example.org' + val.poster_path '>";
```

First line is okay for me. But i need second line code to work to get the value.
I've read some articles that explains about this issue but i still don't get the answer.

All I want is to put the poster_path inside the img tag.

Comment: `read_html += '<img src="https://example.org/' + val.poster_path + '">';`

Comment: @Chaska `val.poster_path = 'nonExistent" onError="executeMaliciousCode()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to concatenate strings and variables like so:

```
read_html += '<img src="https://example.org/' + val.poster_path + '">';
```

Snippet:

```js
var val = {
    poster_path: "something.html"
}

var read_html = '<img src="https://example.org' + val.poster_path + '">';

console.log(read_html)
```

---

Or if you like [ES6 template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) better (more concise):

```
read_html += `<img src="https://example.org/${val.poster_path}">`;
```

Note that the above code will not work on:

- Any version of Internet Explorer
- Edge 12 or below
- Firefox 33 or below
- Chrome 40 or below
- Safari 9 or below
- Opera 28 or below
- StackOverflow's Stack Snippets (as of December 2018)

[CanIUse link](https://caniuse.com/#search=template%20literals)

Comment: That makes no escaping - `val.posterPath` could very well include executable JS that you will blindly put in the DOM and force the user to run. This can then be used by an attacker.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this with **`**.

While using **`** you need to use`${}` to access any variable

```js
let val ={
  path : 'hello.img'
}

var read_html = `<img src='https://example.org\' + ${val.path} \'>`;

console.log(read_html)
```